How to turn off loop in signalr?
Every time I refresh the page I lose data so I have to use a loop and it can't help me turn it off
private bool _isDisconnected = false;

public async Task RecordAccess(int id)
 {
     while (!_isDisconnected)
     {
     Context.Items["TempNewsId"] = id;

     _connectionNewsIdMap.Add(Context.ConnectionId, id);


         await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceivedRecord", id, _username, true, DateTime.Now);

         await Task.Delay(3000);
     }
 }

 public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
 {
     if (Context.Items.TryGetValue("TempNewsId", out var tempNewsId))
     {
         var newsId = (int)tempNewsId;

         _connectionNewsIdMap.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);

         _isDisconnected = true;

         await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceivedRecord", 0, _username, false, DateTime.Now);
     }

     await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
 }


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

_isDisconnected in your code is a global variable, and the disconnection of a single user may affect other clients.
So please use private ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool> _connectionStatusMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool>(); to manage the status of each connected client.
Here is the sample code
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool> _connectionStatusMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool>();

public async Task RecordAccess(int id)
{
    var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
    _connectionStatusMap[connectionId] = false;
    // !_connectionStatusMap[connectionId] like _isDisconnected in your code
    while (!_connectionStatusMap[connectionId])
    {
        Context.Items["TempNewsId"] = id;

        _connectionNewsIdMap.Add(connectionId, id);

        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceivedRecord", id, _username, true, DateTime.Now);

        await Task.Delay(3000);

        if (_connectionStatusMap[connectionId])
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
{
    var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
    
    if (Context.Items.TryGetValue("TempNewsId", out var tempNewsId))
    {
        var newsId = (int)tempNewsId;

        _connectionNewsIdMap.Remove(connectionId);
        _connectionStatusMap[connectionId] = true;

        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceivedRecord", 0, _username, false, DateTime.Now);
    }

    await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
}

